# Overlapped panels

Tags: jpanel, mouseevent

We are creating an interactive graphical model in java using swing. We model is represented as nodes (shape objects) and links (arrow lines). We draw the shapes (with listeners) on jpanels and we render them on a JFrame. We realized that when panels overlap they do not respond to click events. A click just toggles them over, but our handlers do not respond to click events.

However, when they don't overlap, they respond.

Comment: Can you show any ScreenShot of your JFrame here.